@Autowired not injecting MqttClient to Listener class
I have a Spring Boot application that I'm using with Mqtt Paho. I've created an Mqtt Configuration class to connect to the broker and subscribe to a test topic. I also have an MqttListener class to handle messages. I can see that the MqttClient bean is being instantiated, but my Mqtt methods will not get trggered.
Here is my MqttClient:
package com.example.javaproject.listener;

@Configuration
public class MqttConfig {

    @Bean
    public MqttClient mqttClient() throws MqttException {
        MqttClient client = new MqttClient(broker, clientId);
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setUserName("username");
        options.setPassword("password".toCharArray());
        client.connect(options);
        if (client.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("client connected");
            client.subscribe("test-topic");
            System.out.println("subscribed to topics");
        }
        return client;

    }

}

Here is my Listener:
package com.example.javaproject.config;

@Service
public class MqttMessageListener  implements  MqttCallbackExtended{

    @Autowired
    MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MqttClient mqttClient;

    public MqttMessageListener(){

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("MqttMessageListener initialized successfully");

    }


    @Override
    public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
        System.out.println("connected message from listener");
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("connection lost");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        String content = mqttMessage.toString();
        Message message = new Message(topic, content);
        System.out.println("message arrived triggered: " + content);

        try{
            messageRepository.save(message);
            System.out.println("message saved to database");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error saving to database: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        System.out.println("delivery complete");
    }
}

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you

You can check if your mqttClient bean is autowired properly, by adding a break point to the MqttMessageListener's init method and checking if th mqttClient is null or not.

Everything looks good. Does the listener print "MqttMessageListener initialized successfully" when application starts? If yes - it works, in such case probably there are no events to listen to.

According to Javadoc you don't need the MqttClient autowired in the listener class. However you need to register the listener by calling  IMqttClient.setCallback(MqttCallback) Check: https://eclipse.dev/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallbackExtended.html

Alex, the listener does print that it has been initialized, and when I check the logs there is in fact an Mqtt client initialized as well. However no mqtt methods work here, even subscribing from the listener class does not get triggered.
